# Space taken by a span element is bigger than the actual text

Tags: html, css

I need the bottom and top lines to be closer to the title, but the font is taking more space than it actually needs.

This is how it looks in practice:
[Actual Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdLkZ.png)

This is how im trying to make it look:
[Ideal Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl1NH.png)

My code:

HTML

```
<div id="title" class="title">
            <h1 id="title-h1">
                <span class="text-title">MINDESIGNS</span>
            </h1>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
h1{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
}

.text-title{
    font-family: 'Thick Thinks', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #303030;
    font-size: 17vw;
    justify-content: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
    user-select: none;
}

.title{
    width: auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #303030;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
    padding-top: 0%;
    padding-bottom: 0%;
}
```

Comment: add a line-height value to your .text-title class - eg. line-height: 1.03em;  .... adjust the value as needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`line-height: 1;` should get you pretty close.

```css
.title {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14vw;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">MINDESIGNS</h1>
```

Comment: I tried using line-height and it kinda helps but now it looks uncentered, is there a way to fix that?

Comment: added a margin so its centered now, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use line height
2. use another div with hr tag then add some styling

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).